# Disk partition has imperfect fraction. Is there something I've messed up?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, disk-usage

[Please note the partition fraction in the line of 104GB Volume.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYrSF.png)

It shows 190.1 GB / 104 GB Available.

The partition on which Ubuntu seems to be installed is the C drive of Windows 10. I had only two partitions, and Ubuntu was installed in this one. Even in windows, the size of C: is still 194 GB. I've a hard disk of 320GB size.

I am worried if both system will interfere to cause some problems. Please suggest some solution to this.

I'm a new user, I apologize if I'm not clear enough. Please guide me.

Update:

```
insiyeah@Insiyah:~$ lsblk -fmip | grep -v loop
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT                      SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
/dev/sda                                                                                                298.1G root  disk  brw-rw----
|-/dev/sda1 ntfs     System Reserved 52643E6A643E5149                                                     500M root  disk  brw-rw----
|-/dev/sda2 ntfs                     0810491A10490FDC                                                    96.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
|-/dev/sda3 ntfs                     ECC84025C83FEC88                                                   102.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
|-/dev/sda4                                                                                                 1K root  disk  brw-rw----
`-/dev/sda5 ext4                     2c670f7c-3563-4429-b69f-ddb9fdf9d76f /                                98G root  disk  brw-rw----
/dev/sr0                                                                                                 1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
```

---

```
insiyeah@Insiyah:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x18208a82

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 204192818 203166771  96.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409602048 625139711 215537664 102.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       204193790 409602047 205408258    98G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       204193792 409602047 205408256    98G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: could you please paste the outputs of those commands `lsblk -fmip | grep -v loop` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @cmak.fr I've pasted the outputs... Please take a look

Comment: that's strange! i'd probably run a `chkdsk`  against the two drives under Windows. Then full shutdown windows (Shift+clic on the sutdown button) and then start Ubuntu and see if it goes better.

Comment: @cmak.fr it got even worse... Now it shows 192.3 GB / 104.0 GB /dev/sda2... Do you think uninstalling Ubuntu will do any good?

Comment: nope, you will have to repair the windows boot

Comment: @cmak.fr can you please redirect me to some source which can guide me to do so...

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows